# How to retrieve data from local file of json to a dictionary in Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I have trouble in retrieving the data from my `JSON` file to a dictionary and then I will access the values inside array of that dictionary to take the time and compare the time what I have done so far is that.

Note: I have multiple timings for one month.

in my `viewDidLoad` I have defined

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/macbook/Desktop/Test/Test/myFile.json"];
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Json data is here %@", fileContent);
```

saving data in dictionary

```
    NSArray *data = [[theFeedString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"data"];
for (NSDictionray *dict in data) {
    NSString *timings = [[dict objectForKey:@"timings"] intValue];
}
```

in my console I get all the data from my json and my json look like this

```
{
 "data": [
{
  "timings": {
    "Sunrise": "07:14 (PKT)",
    "Sunset": "18:15 (PKT)",
    "Midnight": "00:45 (PKT)"
  }
},
{
  "timings": {
    "Sunrise": "07:13 (PKT)",
    "Sunset": "06:40 (PKT)",
    "Midnight": "00:45 (PKT)"
  }
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this way, where `Palettes.json` is a local file.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Palettes" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Let me know if there is any query.

**UPDATE**

According to your Output of JSON, you will get data array like this,

```
NSArray *data = json["data"];
[data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *timings = object["timings"];
    NSString *sunrise = timings["Sunrise"];
}];
```

You can iterate through `data array` to get `timings`

Comment: but how do I save the data in dictionary

Comment: @iOSDeveloper you will get the dictionary from the json itself

Comment: so that I can access from dictionary each daily timings and inside timings values can be retrievable

Comment: how? would you give me an example please

Comment: thank dear please make it in dictionary so I can access the arrays of timings and values like sunrise from that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167257/discussion-between-ppl-and-ios-developer).